# Linux : Setting CLASSPATH inside Linux Script

Tags: linux

I  have a java  file to be exected in LInux server .
I am writing a script for this .
My question is inside the Script do i need to mention name of each jar as shown below 
CLASSPATH=./lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar:./lib/mail.jar:./lib/javax.servlet.jar:./lib/ojdbc.jar:./lib/activation.jar:./lib/commons-logging.jar:.

or can i mention as *.jar directly as shown

CLASSPATH=./lib/*.jar

Please share your inputs . Thanks

Comment: I think you cannot use wildcards. So it's the first way. Nevertheless if that's a maven project, there's maven-lib plugin which generates a classpath var inside the manifest and includes all dependencies which are required. This way you don't need to manage this yourself.

Comment: Thanks but this is not a Maven Project

Comment: also check this out http://stackoverflow.com/q/219585/1007273

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple script:

```
CLASSPATH=
for f in ./lib/*; do CLASSPATH=$f:$CLASSPATH;done;
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH.
```

It can be expanded to look better:

```
CLASSPATH=
for f in ./lib/*
do
    CLASSPATH=$f:$CLASSPATH
done
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH.
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail? I can't understand what are you asking?